# C# PostGres Authentification with Kerberos and Npgsql

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, kerberos, npgsql

We want to connect a rich client application to a Postgres database using Kerberos authentication. For the dev we have a Kerberos server installed (without Active Directory). I can't find any info to make this connection. The Kerberos.Net library does not seem to be compliant with this project which uses Framework 3.5.
Does anyone have any clues?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is your project really using .NET Framework 3.5? If that's the case, none of the recent versions of Npgsql support it, and there's a good chance you won't be able to make it work.

Otherwise, Npgsql does support Kerberos authentication, [see the docs](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/security.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We use an old version of Npgsql but we found that it didn't work with Postgres 12. So we migrated the application to 4.6.2 and also updated Npgsql to 4.1.7. But still some difficulties to use Posgres. Still looking for help.